# How to control the Appearance of UIPickerView 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can anyone point me in the right direction here.
Im trying to use a UIPickerView that is displaying images.
The images are too big for the default pickerview setup so I was wondering how I could control how big the rows in the UIPickerView are and how wide the translucent selection bar is to accomodate for their custom size.

Can anyone provide some guidelines as to how big I should make the row images or where a good tutorial / book chapter is on this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is Cocoa-related.  The exclusion of the Cocoa tag was unnecessary.  He's asking a question relating to a framework, and his question falls under multiple umbrellas underneath the larger 'Cocoa' umbrella.  It's fine.

Comment: @Mr_Spock Not really. UIImageView is part of the UIKit framework, which in turn is part of Cocoa Touch, hence the cocoa-touch tag. See the description of both tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) instead of trying to customize a UIPickerView?  It is designed to enable you to allow the user to pick from their library of images if you use the sourceType of UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary.

There is sample code on how to use this controller at http://zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/

If the images are not from the user's library, then I would suggest you scale the images down to fit the constraints of the UIPickerView, or use a tabelView with the images laid out in it for the user to select.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, What I mean is what is the practice for scaling down images / how do you know what size they should be to fit into the rows of the picker view correctly.

Comment: If they are true images (rather than icons/shapes) you probably can't keep enough detail at the size you want to show.  The minimum "hit-size" for a touch point is about 44x44 pixels.  I made shapes in my app that were scaled to about double that and it worked well.  Much bigger than 100 pixels started drawing strangely in the UIPicker controller.  I have not re-run on a retina display, but you might want to start there.